# Text To Speech: speech method is not working

Tags: java, android, text-to-speech

I tried to implement Text To Speech, but when I wrote a method it's not showing the speech method correctly. Following is my method's code

MainActivity.java

```
private void ConvertTextToSpeech() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        text = et.getText().toString();
        // If no text is typed, tts will read out 'You haven't typed text'
        // else it reads out the text you typed
        if (text.length() == 0) {
            tts.speak("You haven't typed text", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
        } else {
            tts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);

        }

    }
```

Instead of appearing like above, it's showing like this

tts.s̶p̶e̶a̶k̶

and my build.gradle(app) is

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.Hacker.texttospeech"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

How to make it work? I think it's an API problem.
I'm trying to implement this on API Level 16.

In case it is an API problem, how to run it on API Level 16+?

Comment: That method is deprecated?

Comment: yes, that's what it is saying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check the documentation for the correct form

> This method was deprecated in API level 21.
>
> As of API level 21, replaced by `speak(CharSequence, int, Bundle, String)`

And if that isn't working, then the problem lies elsewhere